# The distinction between past and present tense in the following sentence

Tags: gramática

> Fuimos al resturante y comimos pasta.

I was doing some exercise on past tense on Spanish language and this very first question made me confused that how this is a past tense.

The application on my mobile said the right answer was

> We went to the resturant and ate pasta.

But why cannot this be

> We go the resturant and eat pasta.

I don't know the way it has been constructed so that it has become a past tense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fuimos* is the past tense form of *ir* (to go). Present tense would be *vamos*. Likewise, the present tense form of *comer* (to eat) is *comemos*.

"***Vamos** al restaurante y **comemos** pasta*" would be present tense, first person, plural.

Comment: Is there a certain trick to know the past tense of any verb like _Vamos_ and _comemos_ ? Or we have to memorize the past tense of verb as well?

Comment: There is a pattern that is followed, though _ir_ is one of the exceptions to the rule. A book such as __501 Spanish Verbs__ shows all of the conjugations of the most commonly used verbs.

Comment: http://conjugation.org also shows the patterns.

Comment: @idiosincrasia23 las conjugaciones verbales en español se rigen por una tabla de "desinencias", que así se le llama a las terminaciones verbales, que en su 80% son aplicables a todos los verbos, y si cambian, también cambian siguiendo unas reglas, bien por la deformación de una letra en diptongo, o bien por el cambio de una desinencia a otra irregular, pero siempre, como he dicho, siguiendo una regla. Lo que no puedes preguntar, amigo, es que porqué un tiempo verbal está en pasado, eso como si yo te digo en inglés que por qué 'ate' es pasado. Porque esa es su forma en pasado y debes conocerla.

Answer (score 2):

Spanish is a bit like Latin in that verbs have fairly complex conjugations and there are several basic conjugations that follow standard rules which, as you fear, have to be memorized. There are three basic conjugations for regular verbs. And then there are oodles of irregular verbs.

Answer (score 1):

Both "comimos" and "fuimos" are past tense. There is a pattern you can follow to form the conjugations, but keep in mind that some verbs (many common ones) are irregular and will vary. This is the model for regular -ar, -er, -ir verbs in the *pretérito perfecto simple*:

```
                    AR       ER/IR
yo                  -é       -í
tú                  -aste    -iste
él/ella/usted       -ó       -ió
nosotros            -amos    -imos
vosotros            -asteis  -isteis
ellos/ellas/ustedes -aron    -ieron
```